# adding <para> tag before the list

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have an existing XML that is something like this:

```xml
<para>
  <ul type="unordered">
    <li>
      <content>
        <para>First thing on the list</para>
      </content>
    </li>
    <li>
      <content>
        <para>Some introductory text for the inner list:</para>
        <ul type="unordered">
          <li>
            <content>
              <para>this is a sublist1</para>
            </content>
          </li>
          <li>
            <content>
              <para>this is a sublist2</para>
            </content>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </content>
    </li>
  </ul>
</para>
```

But What I want them is the inner list element to be wrapped in a `<para>`.

```xml
<para>
  <ul type="unordered">
    <li>
      <content>
        <para>First thing on the list</para>
      </content>
    </li>
    <li>
      <content>
        <para>
          Some introductory text for the inner list:
          <ul type="unordered">
            <li>
              <content>
                <para>this is a sublist1</para>
              </content>
            </li>
            <li>
              <content>
                <para>this is a sublist2</para>
              </content>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </para>
      </content>
    </li>
  </ul>
</para>
```

I have code that checks if there is a list within a list and adds a  element.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as I get the `<para>` added to each sublist. And I add them to the parent (`if eachl.append(para) to element.append(para)`), I get the whole sublist moved to the parent:

```
if element.tag == "ul":
    element.tag = "list"
    element.set("type", "unordered")
    list_nlist = element.findall("li/ul")
    if len(list_nlist) != 0:
        for eachl in list_nlist:
            para = copy.deepcopy(eachl)
            para.tag = "para"
            eachl.clear()
            eachl.insert(0, para)
            eachl.append(para)
```

Comment: Your code sample does not correspond to your XML sample.

Comment: updated the query. The existing xml generted is automated and I cant see the intermediate generation.

Comment: Are you limited to using Python? This task would be quite straight-forward in XSLT.

Comment: yes I am. and I am using markdown  and this piece of code is in my private extension.